# What does preserveWS parameter mean in ConstructingParser?

Tags: scala

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/xml/parsing/ConstructingParser.scala

Neither source code or document explains the meaning of `preserveWS`:

```
object ConstructingParser {
  def fromFile(inp: File, preserveWS: Boolean) =
    new ConstructingParser(Source.fromFile(inp), preserveWS).initialize

  def fromSource(inp: Source, preserveWS: Boolean) =
    new ConstructingParser(inp, preserveWS).initialize
}
```

Does anybody know what it means?

Thanks.

Comment: Preserve whitespace, presumably.

Answer (score 1):

as Mat suggested, it indeed means "preserve whitespace".